# How to share data among applications when we don't know which app is provider but first app has stored data

Tags: android

I have 5(any number) android applications which will share some `data`.

Now when 1st/2nd/3rd..(i couldn't know) android application will get installed by user, it will save a string in the memory(internal memory),

When any other application will get installed, it should know that one of the app has already `written` data and now it should act as `user` of this data.

To sum up, first app installed will act as provider and others as users...but all the applications can be potential `provider` and other as users..

**Is this feasible?**

i tried using `file/shared preference/content providers`...but in `file`, you should know file path before using it which is dependent on package name..

In `shared preference`, we have to create package context..
In `content provider`, we have to import provider package..

My real motive is, actually in each app, i register the user first time...

now i want , if user install 2nd app from me, it can just use data of first app and do not ask for register..

but the problem is i don't know which app will be installed first by user..
Please help if i can use some other approach??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found one thread related to this...

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/W-oOa0x9amg
http://android.bigresource.com/Android-How-to-share-data-between-applications-with-no-dependency-HRMMGMIkL.html

This thread pretty much answers my question, in terms of feasibility and options i have for this scenario.